# Code equivalent to += assignment to an event

Tags: c#, events, syntactic-sugar

I was wondering if anyone could tell me the raw code equivalent to the += operator for adding a method to an event. I am curious to how it it works from a technical standpoint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `event` defines a set of methods including "add" and "remove" (in the same way that a property defines "get" and "set"). to this is effectively:

```
obj.add_SomeEvent(handler);
```

Internally, the event could do anything; there are 2 common cases:

- events with a delegate field (including "field-like" events)
- `EventHandlerList` implementations

With a delegate, it effectively uses `Delegate.Combine`:

```
handler = Delegate.Combine(handler, value);
```

With an `EventHandlerList` there is a key object:

```
Events.AddHandler(EventKey, value);
```